# Nil Value for Tree a -> a in Haskell

Tags: haskell, tree, null

So I have a tree defined as

```
data Tree a = Leaf | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving Show
```

I know I can define Leaf to be Leaf a. But I really just want my nodes to have values. My problem is that when I do a search I have a return value function of type

```
Tree a -> a
```

Since leafs have no value I am confused how to say if you encounter a leaf do nothing. I tried `nil`, `" "`, `' '`, `[]` nothing seems to work.

Edit Code

```
data Tree a = Leaf | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving Show


breadthFirst   :: Tree a -> [a]
breadthFirst x =  _breadthFirst [x]

_breadthFirst    :: [Tree a] -> [a]
_breadthFirst [] =  []
_breadthFirst xs =  map treeValue xs ++
                _breadthFirst (concat (map immediateChildren xs))

immediateChildren                       :: Tree a -> [Tree a]
immediateChildren (Leaf)              =  []
immediateChildren (Node n left right) =  [left, right]

treeValue                         :: Tree a -> a
treeValue (Leaf)                =  //this is where i need nil
treeValue (Node n left right)   =  n

test = breadthFirst (Node 1 (Node 2 (Node 4 Leaf Leaf) Leaf) (Node 3 Leaf (Node 5 Leaf Leaf)))

main =
  do putStrLn $ show $ test
```

Comment: You want to search for a node with a certain value? Then `Maybe a` is probably a good return type.

Comment: No its doing a breadth first traversal and then printing the values it finds in order. Problem is it comes across leaf and is like what do i do, and i was to say nothing just go on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So my solution in this case would be to use `Maybe` and `mapMaybe`. To put it simply, you'd change `treeValue` to

```
treeValue                         :: Tree a -> Maybe a
treeValue (Leaf)                =  Nothing
treeValue (Node n left right)   =  Just n
```

Then instead of using `map` to combine this, use `mapMaybe` (from Data.Maybe) which will automatically strip away the `Just` and ignore it if it's `Nothing`.

```
 mapMaybe treeValue xs
```

Voila!

`Maybe` is Haskell's way of saying "Something might not have a value" and is just defined like this:

```
data Maybe a = Just a | Nothing
```

It's the moral equivalent of having a Nullable type. Haskell just makes you acknowledge the fact that you'll have to handle the case where it is "null". When you need them, [Data.Maybe](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Maybe.html) has tons of useful functions, like `mapMaybe` available.

Comment: So would I need to change all my type A to maybe?

Comment: No, just that one function, you're just wrapping stuff in `Maybe` so that `mapMaybe` can filter out the "nil" values. `mapMaybe` will also unwrap everything nicely for you

Comment: I am getting a error not that says
map treeValue xs ++ _breadthFirst (concat (map immediateChildren xs))
*** Term           : map treeValue xs
*** Type           : [Maybe a]
*** Does not match : [a]
*** Because        : unification would give infinite type

Answer (score 12):

In Haskell, types do not have an "empty" or `nil` value by default. When you have something of type `Integer`, for example, you *always* have an actual number and never anything like `nil`, `null` or `None`.

Most of the time, this behavior is good. You can never run into null pointer exceptions when you don't expect them, because you can never have *nulls* when you don't expect them. However, sometimes we really need to have a `Nothing` value of some sort; your tree function is a perfect example: if we don't find a result in the tree, we have to signify that somehow.

The most obvious way to add a "null" value like this is to just wrap it in a type:

```
data Nullable a = Null | NotNull a
```

So if you want an `Integer` which could also be `Null`, you just use a `Nullable Integer`. You could easily add this type yourself; there's nothing special about it.

Happily, the Haskell standard library has a type like this already, just with a different name:

```
data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a
```

you can use this type in your tree function as follows:

```
 treeValue :: Tree a -> Maybe a
 treeValue (Node value _ _) = Just value
 treeValue Leaf             = Nothing
```

You can use a value wrapped in a `Maybe` by pattern-matching. So if you have a list of `[Maybe a]` and you want to get a `[String]` out, you could do this:

```
showMaybe (Just a) = show a
showMaybe Nothing  = ""

myList = map showMaybe listOfMaybes
```

Finally, there are a bunch of useful functions defined in the `Data.Maybe` module. For example, there is `mapMaybe` which maps a list and throws out all the `Nothing` values. This is probably what you would want to use for your `_breadthFirst` function, for example.

Answer (score 7):

In this case, you can simply use a list comprehension instead of `map` and get rid of `treeValue`:

```
_breadthFirst xs = [n | Node n _ _ <- xs] ++ ...
```

This works because using a pattern on the left hand side of `<-` in a list comprehension skips items that don't match the pattern.

Comment: This is the answer which tries to teach the OP to avoid the question. There's no need for a treeValue function, only to slice the tree into a (possibly empty) list of root values and a (ditto) list of children.

Answer (score 3):

This function `treeValue :: Tree a -> a` can't be a total function, because not all `Tree a` values actually contain an `a` for you to return! A `Leaf` is analogous to the empty list `[]`, which is still of type `[a]` but doesn't actually contain an `a`.

The `head` function from the standard library has the type `[a] -> a`, and it also can't work all of the time:

```
*Main> head []
*** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list
```

You *could* write `treeValue` to behave similarly:

```
treeValue :: Tree a -> a
treeValue Leaf = error "empty tree"
treeValue (Node n _ _) = n
```

But this won't actually help you, because now `map treeValue xs` will throw an error if any of the `xs` are `Leaf` values.

Experienced Haskellers usually try to avoid using `head` and functions like it for this very reason. Sure, there's no way to get an `a` from any given `[a]` or `Tree a`, but maybe you don't need to. In your case, you're really trying to get a *list* of `a` from a *list* of `Tree`, and you're happy for `Leaf` to simply contribute nothing to the list rather than throw an error. But `treeValue :: Tree a -> a` doesn't help you build that. It's the **wrong** function to help you solve your problem.

A function that helps you do whatever you need would be `Tree a -> Maybe a`, as explained very well in some other answers. That allows you to *later* decide what to do about the "missing" value. When you go to use the `Maybe a`, if there's really nothing else to do, you can call `error` then (or use `fromJust` which does exactly that), or you can decide what else to do. But a `treeValue` that claims to be able to return an `a` from any `Tree a` and then calls `error` when it can't denies any caller the ability to decide what to do if there's no `a`.