# Non-exhaustive Pattern exception, for bind but not for do

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, list-comprehension, monads

To put into context, I was converting a list comprehension (from [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16488043/nil-value-for-tree-a-a-in-haskell)) doing "pattern filtering" to its monadic counterpart (do and bind), then I meet an exception.

I start with these definitions (bf holds for breadthFirst),

**context, data and helper**

```
data Tree a = Leaf | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving Show
let test = Node 1 (Node 2 (Node 4 Leaf Leaf) Leaf) (Node 3 Leaf (Node 5 Leaf Leaf))
let nextChild = concatMap (\x -> case x of; Leaf -> []; Node n l r -> [l,r])
```

**function to test**

```
let bfLc xs   | null xs = [] | otherwise = [ n | Node n _ _ <- xs] ++ (bfLc $ nextChild xs)   
let bfDo xs   | null xs = [] | otherwise = (do {Node n _ _ <- xs; return n})  ++ (bfDo $ nextChild xs)
let bfBind xs | null xs = [] | otherwise = (xs >>= \(Node n _ _) -> [n]) ++ (bfBind $ nextChild xs)
```

And I do these evaluations,

```
bfLc [test]
[1,2,3,4,5]

bfDo [test]
[1,2,3,4,5]

bfBind [test]
[1,2,3,4*** Exception: <interactive>:103:53-72: Non-exhaustive patterns in lambda
```

But I learned from [there](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/monads.html)

> The do syntax provides a simple shorthand for chains of monadic operations. The essential translation of do is captured in the following two rules:
>
> ```
>   do e1 ; e2      =  e1 >> e2  
>   do p <- e1; e2  =  e1 >>= \p -> e2
> ```

Why does `bfBind` fail contrary to `bfDo` despite they are equivalent ?
Personally, I was expected they all failed, I don't know why list comprehension or Do notation succeed ? (Then if you can answer also this sub question)

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because failed pattern matches in `do` notation call the `fail` function from the Monad class.

In particular, this is how your expression actually gets desugared:

```
do {p <- e; stmts}  = let ok p = do {stmts}
                          ok _ = fail "..."
  in e >>= ok
```

Here `p` is any pattern, like the `Node n _ _` from your example.

(Take a look at the section on [do expressions](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/exps.html#sect3.14) in the Haskell report.)

The `Monad` instance for `[]` defines `fail` as follows:

```
fail _ = []
```

Comment: The definition of `fail` in the `Maybe` instance is the most compelling IMO